# Add a watch to an instance instead of a variable

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Is there a way to add a watch to an instance of a object, instead to a variable? I have an object that is passed through various functions via parameters, and the parameters name may change in each function, so I'd like to add a watch that would be 'fixed' to that instance, regardless of the variable its currently assigned to.

Does anyone knows a way to do that? I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add the item to the Watch window, try right-clicking on that entry and choose Make Object ID.  Then add a watch for the particular ID (1#, 2#, etc.) [See this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/04/make-objectid-vstipdebug0015.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Yes, i already knew that, and its very usefull, but the problem is, i add a watch to a variable, lets say its called myObject. then I pass this object to a function, throught a parameter called myParameter. The watch i added to myObject won't work inside the function.

Comment: Correct, the watch on myObject won't work.  Once you create the watch on myObject you have to create a second watch on the ID that you assigned.  You should then be able to use the ID watch regardless of where you are at.

Comment: But thats the point, is there a way to add a ID watch? I know the ID of the object will be shown in the value of the object, but i will still have to add a watch to each reference.

Comment: The link I provided shows how to create a watch on the ID.  If, for example, the object shows "{1#}" as the ID, then you add a new watch for "1#"

Comment: Sorry Pedro, I havent checked that link. I know its a long time, but i was revisiting my questions e re-read your comment, so i Marked your answer as the correct one. thanks.